# Twitter Bootstrap + Less

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm a web designer newbie and just found out LESS and Twitter's bootstrap. As in the documentation, it said that bootstrap can be modified using LESS.

My question is, how to modify/customize bootstrap using LESS? I usually compile less using javascript. Is there any good tutorial links/series teach how to maximize bootstrap customization?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lengthy less documentation right on the bootstrap page that you can go over. It lists most variables and mixins that you can easily identify and modify to your liking.

You can find the documentation here: [Using LESS with Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html).

There is also a Download section on the bootstrap documentation page where you can modify the default styles and customize the bootstrap to your liking right on the website and then have everything downloaded on a customized package.

You can find the custom downloads section here: [Customize and download](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's not bootstrap-specific, but the [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/) website has some excellent information, too. The "[usage](http://lesscss.org/#usage)" section is particularly relevant to your question, I think.